# Is it necessary to var scope loop variables in CFScript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When using CFML and CF9 I usually var scope my loop variables; in this case `local.i`, for example:

```
<cfloop list="#this.list#" index="local.i">
  <cfif Len(local.i) GT 10>
    // do something
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I recently started converting some stuff into CFScript, and (to my disappointment I found out that there is no way to loop over a list in CFScript) I'm wondering if I should still var scope my loop variables, and how:

```
for (i = 1; LTE ListLen(this.list); i = i + 1 ) {
  if (Len(ListGetAt(this.list, i) GT 10)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Should I be doing `local.i = 1` and `local.i = local.i + 1` istead of the sample code in my example? Is it necessary?

**EDIT**: I should also ask if the CFScript form of my CFML loop is correct; I ask because I just noticed that my CFML loop uses a `,` (comma and space) for the `delimiter` argument, which seems non-existence in the CFScript version of the loop.

Comment: One thing I would note -- Unless your "do something" can change the length of your list, I would store it in a variable and loop to that.  My understanding is that the way you have this written, the listlen() operation will be called for every loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All functions still use the variables scope by default if you don't specify one, which would make omitting it not-thread-safe. Wherever you previously should have used `var` you should now use `local`.

As for the comma+space delimiter, two things:

1. In case you aren't aware, the delimiters argument of list function is not for multi-character delimiters, it is for multiple delimiters; so your list will be split for each occurrence of a comma, as well as each occurrence of a space.
2. You use the same argument as part of your `listLen` and `listGetAt` methods, like so:

   ```
   for (i = 1; LTE ListLen(this.list, ', '); i = i + 1 ) {
     if (Len(ListGetAt(this.list, i, ', ') GT 10)) {
       // do something
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks! Just to be clear, when you say "UDFs still use the variables scope" - does that definition include any functions I declared myself in my CFC component?

Comment: No, any method inside a CFC will default to the local scope. The UDFs I was referring to would be anywhere else (eg custom tag, cfm template, etc)

Comment: Unscoped variables default to the variables scope, so you'll want to make sure you scope all of your local variables using either the new "local" scope or using the "var" keyword.

Comment: Actually, Tony, you're absolutely right. I was confused about the default if no scope was specified. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: With CF9 and above, you can use <= instead of LTE, > instead of GT, and i++ instead of i = i+1

Answer (score 6):

You definitely need to use the local scope as Adam says, but in the case of loops I think there's a strong case for using the "var" keyword rather than the "local" prefix for the sake of readability. With CF9 you're no longer forced to place var declarations at the top of the function, so all you need do is add "var" to your "for" condition statement for all the index "i" variables to become thread safe.

Taking in Ben's good point about saving the length of the list before starting the loop, and using the more concise i++ increment style your code would be:

```
var listLength  =   ListLen( this.list );
for (var i = 1; LTE listLength; i++ ) {
    if (Len(ListGetAt(this.list, i) GT 10)) {
    // do something
    }
}
```